XSLT - Retrieve node based on sibling's value
I have below sample XML:
<?xml version="1.0"encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Root>
    <Record>
        <JobProfile>
            <Status>
                <Code>Pending</Code>
            </Status>
            <ID>
                <Code>007</Code>
            </ID>
        </JobProfile>
        <JobProfile>
            <Status>
                <Code>Active</Code>
            </Status>
            <ID>
                <Code>003</Code>
            </ID>
        </JobProfile>
        <JobProfile>
            <Status>
                <Code>Terminated</Code>
            </Status>
            <ID>
                <Code>004</Code>
            </ID>
        </JobProfile>
    </Record>
</Root>

I need to get output like below:
<Root>
    <Record>
        <ID>003</ID>
    </Record>
</Root>

The Logic is  - Read the input XML, find the node where JobProfile/Status/Code = "Active". Once found, read the JobProfile/ID/Code at the sibling's level and write it in the output.
Tried the below XSLT but it's not working
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="/Root/Record">
        <ID>
            <xsl:for-each select="Record/JobProfile">
                <xsl:if test="Status/Code='Active'">
                    <xsl:value-of select="ID/Code"/>
                </xsl:if>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </ID>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>


Use
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="/Root/Record/JobProfile[Status/Code != 'Active']"/>

    <xsl:template match="/Root/Record/JobProfile[Status/Code = 'Active']">
      <ID>
        <xsl:value-of select="ID/Code"/>
      </ID>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>


Can you add explanation for users less familar with XSLT specifically why you have <xsl:template match="/Root/Record/JobProfile[Status/Code != 'Active']"/> and how the <xsl:template match="/Root/Record/JobProfile[Status/Code = 'Active']"> works re: context of that selection.

@MarkSchultheiss, there a books like https://cranesoftwrights.github.io/books/#ptux and articles like https://lenzconsulting.com/how-xslt-works/ for those who want a deeper explanation, I don't need to write that in any answer solving a particular problem.

Use:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  
  <!-- Identity template : copy all nodes, no attributes in your xml-->   
  <xsl:template match="node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- filter JobProfile which is not Active and all Status elements-->   
  <xsl:template match="JobProfile[not(Status/Code = 'Active')]|Status"/>
  
  <!-- skip JobProfile|Code but apply templates to use  ID-->   
  <xsl:template match="JobProfile|Code">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>


Just laziness :-). I will correct it

Corrected, it was meant as a alternative for @Martin Honnen's answer
